# Finding leak underground of sprinklers system

Tags: irrigation, water, repair

There is an area in my yard that is muddy. I suspect there is a small leak of the underground pipes.  To avoid randomly digging the entire area (which about 20ft x 10ft), is there a reliable way to pinpoint the leak to a more specific location before digging?  Preferably not needing expensive professional tools.

Comment: You could try dowsing.  It takes a little practice.

Comment: First verify if the sprinklers are leaking. Probably turn off the main valve for a few days and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @blacksmith37 During the winter months, the area was as dry as its surrounding. We started watering again, and got the mud area.

Comment: @chenmunka I believe dowsing is for locating the pipes and not the leak.  Looking at the sprinkler heads, I can guess where the pipes are.

Comment: It is possible to dowse the location of the leak.  You detect pooling of water to the sides of the pipe.

Comment: We think where we would put the pipes in a new system, then dig. Higher chance of leak near elbows or tees. Also dig where we see others have been carelessly digging.